# Numeric column is coerced to character column when another character column is modified

Tags: r, coercion

I have a data frame with two columns, the first one contains numbers, the second one strings. My problem is: once I replace a string in the second column by another string, the first column is coerced from `class` numeric to character. Here is an example:

```
df <- data.frame(num = c(1,2), char = c("a", "b"), stringsAsFactors = F)
class(df$num) # "numeric"
class(df$char) # "character"
df[df$char == "a", ] <- "c"
class(df$char) # "character" 
class(df$num) # "character" !!
```

What's the reason for this behavior and how to stop it?

Answer (score 2):

I found my error: `df[df$char == "a", ] <- "c"` overwrites the whole row, which is why the first column is coerced. The correct way to replace "a" by "c" is: `df$char[df$char == "a"] <- "c"`.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your answer. One other option is `df[df[["char"]] == "a", "char"] <- "c"`. It's good to know both because the one in your answer is a little easier to type, but the one in my comment will work with variables. `$` doesn't work with variables, e.g., if you have `my_col <- "char"`, then `df[df[[my_col]] == "a", my_col] <- "c"` will work.

Answer (score 0):

Look at df after you change it:

```
> df
  num char
1   c    c
2   2    b
>
```

So of course $num has become character.  Your command (because of its comma syntax) identified entire rows to be changed.

A different substitution command

```
df[df == "a"] <- "c"
```

does what you were expecting.